# Integral by parts the function in the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

There is the integral of the function $(\sin x)^2\ln x$ in the interval $(0,1)$, which I am asked to find if it converges.

I tried integration by parts but I came up with the integral of $\sin(2x)/x$ and here I stopped as I found difficulty in calculating this integral according to the integration methods.

> How can I proceed?

I would appreciate for your quidance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions) to evaluate the integral by parts. In terms of the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral), $$\int_0^1\sin^2x\ln xdx=\left[\frac{\sin^2x}{x}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{\sin 2xdx}{x}=\sin1-\operatorname{Si}(2)$$because $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}=0$. But just for a convergence test, we can use a comparison. Since the logarithm is negative and the sine is bounded, you could argue$$\left|\int_0^1\sin^2x\ln xdx\right|\le\left|\int_0^1\ln xdx\right|=[x-x\ln x]_0^1=1,$$using $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\ln x=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful quidance. Would it be possible to use Direct Compatison test as well!?

Comment: @Magda Yes. See my edit.

Comment: It is absolutely clear, really Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no problem for the convergence, because
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\sin^2x\ln x=0
$$
so you can extend the function by continuity over $[0,1]$. (Use $x\to0^+$, if you prefer, but since the function is only defined for $x>0$, there is no issue.)

Why is the limit $0$? Because already
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=0
$$
which is essentially the same as
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^t}{t}=\infty
$$